# Load View after applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, background, viewcontroller

I want to present a ViewController every time the app starts even from background, I have this code:

```
mainViewController *mainController = [[mainViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.window.rootViewController;
UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *) mainController;
[src presentModalViewController:dst animated:YES];
```

The ViewController loads becuase the keyboard pops up but the screen is black. Anyway thank you!

Comment: Could you elaborate on the views present in the view controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok I figured it out, I took the View I wanted to load out of the mainstoryboard and put it in a nib and the just used initWithNib.